# If line has one point inside an infinite cone, will it cross the boundary (at least once)?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

**Question:**

Consider (double) infinite cone for which boundary is defined by the following implicit equation for $\vec{x} = (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

$$ F(\vec{x}) = F(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2 \tan^2 \theta = 0 $$

So, boundary is a set of all points $\vec{x}$ that satisfy $F(\vec{x}) = 0 $. Then, define inside of the cone as set of all points $\vec{x}$ with $F(\vec{x}) < 0 $.

Now, define line to be set of all points $\vec{x}$ such that given fixed $\vec{x}_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $\vec{v} = (v_x, v_y, v_z)$, it can be written as $\vec{x} = \vec{x}_0 + \vec{v}t $, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

If there is a point on the line that is inside the cone (I believe without any loss of generality one can take it to be $\vec{x}_0$, if not - reparametrize), is there a point in the line that is in the boundary, in other words, $\vec{x}$ that is both in the line and that has $F(\vec{x})=0$? Geometrically, my intuition tells me that such a result is true and could be proven.

**My approach:**

Using appropriate rotation around $z$ axis of both $\vec{x}_0$ and $\vec{v}$ one can obtain equivalent problem for which $\vec{v} = (v_x, 0, v_z)$. In that case, if $\vec{x}$ is on the line and has $F(\vec{x}) = 0$ then it amounts to $\vec{F}(\vec{x}_0 + \vec{v}t) = 0$ for at least one value of $t$. Using implicit function $F$, one can write this as a second order polynomial in $t$.

$$ F(\vec{x}_0 + \vec{v}t) = t^2 (v_x^2 - v_z^2 \tan^2 \theta) + 2t (xv_x - zv_z \tan^2 \theta) + (x^2+y^2 - z^2\tan^2\theta) = 0$$

This is in the form $at^2 + 2bt + c = 0$ and it has solutions if and only if $\Delta = b^2 - ac \geq 0$. Using our results of computations, this is equivalent to the following.

$$ \Delta = (xv_x - zv_z \tan^2 \theta)^2- (v_x^2 - v_z^2 \tan^2 \theta)(x^2+y^2 - z^2\tan^2\theta) $$

Here, I note that in the case of $ v_x^2 \geq v_z^2 \tan^2 \theta $, the second term is positive as $\vec{x}_0$ is inside the cone, and $\Delta \geq 0$.

Now, consider a case where $ v_x^2 < v_z^2 \tan^2 \theta $. One simple case of this would be that $v_x = 0$. In that case, we have the following.

$$ \Delta = z^2 v_z^2 \tan^4 \theta + v_z^2 \tan^2 \theta(x^2+y^2 - z^2\tan^2\theta) = v_z^2 \tan^2 \theta (x^2 + y^2) \geq 0 $$

So, now I am just left with the case of $ v_x^2 < v_z^2 \tan^2 \theta $ and $v_x \neq 0$. Unfortunately, after trying usual inequalities as Cauchy-Schwarz, triangle inequality, and trying to expand (or factor) a square of sum, I could not get anything useful.

I really would appreciate your help and advice!

Comment: @Tavish I don't think this is true as you can have line that goes through the origin and is not along the axis of the cone, but none of the points lie outside the cone (take angle of line with respect to the cone's axis to be sufficiently small).

Comment: True. Then consider cases based on whether  the line passes through the origin.

Comment: If you selected any plane containing the line of interest and considered the intersection of the plane with the cone, wouldn't this be equivalent to the statement that all conic sections are convex? The latter is a 2d problem and likely much easier to prove given the classification of conic sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that for $v_x^2 \lt v_z^2 \tan^2\theta$, $\Delta \ge 0$. Expanding and cancelling terms, this is equivalent to $$ -2xzv_x v_z \tan^2\theta \ge y^2 v_x^2 -\tan^2\theta \ (x^2 v_z^2 +y^2 v_z^2 +z^2 v_x^2)\\ \iff \tan^2\theta \big[ (xv_z +zv_x)^2 +y^2 v_z^2 \big]  \ge y^2 v_x^2  $$ But this is true as the LHS is $$\ge y^2 v_z^2 \tan^2\theta \gt y^2 v_x^2 $$ by the starting assumption.

Comment: I don't think this is true: take $\vec{x}_0 = (0,1,10)$ and $\vec{v} = (1,0,0)$ then line is given by all points $\vec{x} = (t, 1, 10)$, and this line doesn't pass through the origin and also does not pass through $(0,0,z)$ for some $z \neq 0$. Also, by my definition of "inside" of the cone, I believe that $(0,0,z)$ is clearly inside the cone as $F((0,0,z)) = -z^2 \tan^2 \theta < 0$.

Comment: @DanielsKrimans My bad, see the new answer.

Comment: this is great, thanks a lot! how did you figure it out? did you have some intuition you were using or was it just trial and error?

Comment: @DanielsKrimans You’re welcome! I saw (intuitively) that some terms were bound to cancel on expanding and after that it should boil down to some obvious inequality, because your claim is very clearly correct.